# Flatten multi-dimensional array to array with dot notation in Laravel

Tags: laravel, collections

I am looking for a way to flatten this array:

```
$array = ['parent' => ['childA' => "value", 'childB' => "value"]];
```

to:

```
$array = ['parent.childA' => "value", 'parent.childB' => "value"];
```

Is there an elegant way to do this in Laravel? For example with [Laravel Collections](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/collections).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [`array_dot()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/helpers#method-array-dot) Laravel helper is done exactly for that:

```
array_dot($array);
```

> The `array_dot` function flattens a multi-dimensional array into a single level array that uses "dot" notation to indicate depth

Answer (score 3):

For **Laravel 5.7** and newer:

take a look at [`Arr::dot()`](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/helpers#method-array-dot)

For **Laravel 5.6** and older:

`array_dot` is the way to go (see Alexeys answer)